# Open dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

I found this question in one of the posts

> Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be open and dense. Show that
>   $$\mathbb{R}=\{x+y:x,y\in A\}$$

The poster stated that it is not too hard to prove but I can't seem to figure out the proof. Can someone 
help me out.

Comment: I don't think the statement is correct. Take for example rationals. Set of rationals is dense and it is open in some sense(non-topological). However sum of any two rationals will again produce rational number.

Comment: @kolobokish what do you mean by "open" in a non-topological sense?

Comment: @kolobokish What in the world do you mean by "open in some sense (non-topological)"?  Open (in mathematics) is a topological property.

Comment: @kolobokish.The set of rationals also came to mind but couldn't justify how it is open

Comment: Nope. Open structure can be stated in many ways. 1.)The inverse of it is closed, i.e. complement of a set that contains all limiting points. 2). It is a member of given topology. So you can take it to be topologically open, or not. Maybe my formulation isn't mathematically correct.

Comment: What the heck??

Comment: @stackuser rest assured the rationals are definitely not open.

Comment: @kolobokish what kind of "open" is that first definition, if not "topologically open"?  Any context that talks about open and closed sets is a topological context.

Comment: @kolobokish Perhaps you are trying to mention that we can choose different topologies on $\Bbb R$, i.e. "open" might describe different sets in different (topological) contexts.

Comment: Never mind. I was wrong. The idea behind what I said, is that I can make rationals to be member of topology.

Comment: Well if there’s ever a time to be “mathematically correct “ it would be on a mathematics question-and-answer site.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say. One generally takes open intervals to form natural topology for reals.

Comment: I changed my mind. I'll insist that I'm right. Take the following construction. Take natural topology of reals. Construct Borel sigma algebra on it. Add this to your topology. Then continue up to the point when you got topology again. Then rationals would be included in you new topology. So they can be considered to be "open". (I'm note sure about constructibility of this new topology. However through transfinite operation it seem to me it should be constructible.)

Comment: In any reasonable interpretation of such a problem, in the absence of any additional assumptions, one has to interpret this in the euclidean topology, not in any topology you feel like in order to make it wrong.

Comment: Several minutes ago you were speaking about mathematical correctness.

Comment: @stackuser  what is the definition of “open” for your problem?

Comment: @Randall openness with the usual topology on R.

Comment: @stackuser  right, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $A$ is open and nonempty, it contains some open interval $J = (a,b)$ with $a < b$.
Consider any $z \in \mathbb R$.  Since $A$ is dense, $z - J = (z-b, z-a)$ contains some member $x$ of $A$.  Thus $x = z - y$ where $a < y < b$, so $z  = x+y$ where $x \in A$ and $y \in A$.