# Let$A$ be an open, dense set in $\mathbb R^n$. Prove that $A + A = \mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I have no idea how to go about this one. What I'm trying to prove is that given some $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ there has to be some $y$ such that both $\frac x 2 + y$ and $\frac x 2 - y$ both are in A.

But I have no idea how to continue. Just hints are appreciated

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3076151/42969 for the one dimensional case.

Comment: For future reference, what kind of query did you use to find this? I tried to search for this before asking

Comment: Also, thanks. I think I can just change interval for open ball and the proof would be the same.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeneral-topology%5D+open+dense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a dense open set, then $A-\frac x2$ and $\frac x2-A$ are dense open sets, so their intersection is a dense open set, and in particular it's nonempty. Choose a point $y\in(A-\frac x2)\cap(\frac x2-A)$; then $\frac x2+y\in A$ and $\frac x2-y\in A$, so $x=(\frac x2+y)+(\frac x2-y)\in A+A$.

**More generally,** if $A$ is a nonempty open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and $B$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R^n$, then $A+B=\mathbb R^n$.

**Proof.** Consider any point $t\in\mathbb R^n$; we have to show that $t\in A+B$.

Since the mapping $x\mapsto t-x$ is a homeomorphism, $t-A$ is a nonempty open set. Since $B$ is dense, $B\cap(t-A)\ne\emptyset$. Choose a point $b\in B\cap(t-A)$. Then $b\in B$, and $b=t-a$ for some $a\in A$, so $t=a+b\in A+B$.